# Authentication failed when using flask_pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm sure that the MONGO_URI is correct because it works well in pymongo.
but when using flask_pymongo, it doesn't work...
here is my test code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_URI'] ='mongodb://root:aaa2016@localhost:27017/mongo_test'
mongo = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO')


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    mongo.db.user.insert({'username': "aaa"})
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

run it and visit 127.0.0.1:5000, a response of 500 is given..

```
OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2016 20:40:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

any help will be appreciated.

update:
here is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2000, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1567, in       handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1641, in  full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "F:\PycharmProjects\flask_\flask_.py", line 12, in hello_world
mongo.db.user.insert({'username': "aaa"})
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 2203, in insert
with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 718, in _get_socket
with server.get_socket(self.__all_credentials) as sock_info:
File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 152, in get_socket
with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 541, in get_socket
sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 306, in  check_auth
auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 436, in authenticate
auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 416, in _authenticate_default
return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 188, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 213, in command
read_concern)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 99, in command
helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, None, allowable_errors)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 196, in _check_command_response
raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to confirm that it works when using PyMongo directly?

Comment: `import pymongo`                                                                                `connection = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://root:aaa2016@localhost:27017/')`    `db = connection.mongo_test`                                       `db.user.insert({'username': "aaa"})`                                                          it works well........@dim

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37945262/edit) your original question and make sure to include all relevant code. Importing PyMongo isn't enough to confirm that you can connect to the database.

Comment: there are all my test codes,and they are almost same to the video shows to me in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-NSNUKk1Kw)  @dirn

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is if you use the `MONGO_URI` config parameter then pymongo attempts to authenticate against the db name included in the string. You should break up the config parameters into the following so you can specify a db name and an auth source.

```
app.config['MONGO_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MONGO_PORT'] = '27017'
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'mongo_test'
app.config['MONGO_USERNAME'] = 'root'
app.config['MONGO_PASSWORD'] = 'aaa2016'
app.config['MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE'] = 'admin' . # root user is typically defined in admin db
```

Comment: May I ask why `MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE` is essential? I execute `db.authenticate(name=xx, password=xxx)`, it failed. But it succeed by adding `source='admin'`.

Comment: I believe that lets pymongo know which db table holds the credentials to authenticate with.

Answer (score 15):

This question may be old, but I was experiencing the same issue and found another solution that might work for others.

Appending `?authSource=admin` to the end of your `MONGO_URI` variable will authenticate your credentials against the admin database, rather than the one you're connecting to.

Example:
`app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://username:password@host:port/db_name?authSource=admin"`

Comment: The simplest solution of all! Thanks! 

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Flask-MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/) and setting mongo config  using `app.config['MONGODB_*']` then, your uri will be generated from those variables e.g.

```
app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = 'project1'
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = '192.168.1.35'
app.config['MONGODB_PORT'] = 12345
app.config['MONGODB_USERNAME'] = 'webapp'
app.config['MONGODB_PASSWORD'] = 'pwd123'
```

However, if you need to add some additional paramters (such query parameter `authSource=admin`) to uri then, you will have to pass mongo config through `app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS']`

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'connect': False,
    'host': 'mongodb://webapp:pwd123@192.168.1.35:12345/project1?authSource=admin'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what it worked for me using flask_pymongo:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_URI']='mongodb://appUser:passwordForAppUser@localhost/app_db?authSource=admin'

mongo=PyMongo(app)
```

Or you can also try this other [example](https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-enable-authenticated-mongodb-access-for-flask-mongoengine-applications/) using MongoEngine instead:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
    
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
        'db': 'app_db',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 27017,
        'username': 'appUser',
        'password': 'passwordForAppUser',
        'authentication_source': 'admin'
}

db = MongoEngine(app)
```